# $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with respect to the box topology is not compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, box-topology

could anyone help to show that $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with respect to the box topology is not compact? Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There’s absolutely nothing wrong with showing non-compactness of $X = \square_{k=0}^\infty [0,1]$ directly by looking at open covers, but there are other ways as well.  For instance:

If $X = {\Large \square}_{k=0}^\infty [0,1]$ were compact, its closed subspace $ {\Large \square}_{k=0}^\infty \{0,1\}$ would be compact, but it’s not hard to show that $ {\Large \square}_{k=0}^\infty \{0,1\}$ is an infinite, closed, discrete set in $X$ and therefore cannot be compact.

Even simpler:

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $x_n \in X$ be the point such that $x_n(n) = 1$ and $x_n(k) = 0$ if $k\ne n$. Now consider the set $A = \{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. It’s infinite, so if $X$ were compact, $A$ would have a limit point in $X$. But it’s not hard to show that $A$ is a closed, discrete subset of $X$ and therefore has no limit point in $X$.

Comment: Just so nobody else gets confused like I did, the square box means "Cartesian product with the box topology", not some kind of missing or mis-rendered character in your browser.

Comment: @Ted: Sorry about that; I used to work a bit with box products and got used to that notation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How to prove that $ {\Large \square}_{k=0}^\infty \{0,1\}$ is closed in $ {\Large \square}_{k=0}^\infty [0,1]$?

Comment: @user: For $n,k\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n(k)=(0,1)$ if $n=k$ and $[0,1]$ otherwise. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=\prod_{k\in\Bbb N}U_n(k)$. Then $U_n$ is open in ${\Large\square}_{k\in\Bbb N}[0,1]$, and $$\left({\Large\square}_{k\in\Bbb N}[0,1]\right)\setminus{\Large\square}_{k\in\Bbb N}\{0,1\}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! Do you think this proof works also for $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$?

Comment: @user: $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ with the box topology? Yes. Or you could you observe that $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ has a closed subspace homeomorphic to ${\Large\square}_{k\in\Bbb N}[0,1]$, and since the latter is not compact, the former cannot be either.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, with the box topology. Thank you!

Comment: @user: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hello! How do you prove that A is closed?

Comment: @Bmo: If $x\notin A$, then either some $x(n)\in(0,1)$, or there are $n\ne m$ such that $x(n)=x(m)=1$, or $x(n)=0$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. In the first two cases $x$ even has a basic open set in the ordinary product topology that is disjoint from $A$, and in the last case $[0,1)^\Bbb N$ is a basic open nbhd of $x$ in the box topology that is disjoint from $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you so much! That's very clear! Just wondering do you mean there's one of the three conditions for some n∈N?

Comment: @Bmo: You’re very welcome. For each $x\notin A$ at least one of the three conditions applies, and if it’s one of the first two conditions, there is at least one $n$ or one pair of $n$ and $m$ for which it applies.

Answer (score 10):

Let $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ be a sequence consisting of only $0$'s and $1$'s and define $U_{a_n}=[0,\frac{3}{4})$ if $a_n=0$ and $U_{a_n}=(\frac{1}{4},1]$ if $a_n=1$. Also, define $U_a=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} U_{a_n}$.

***Exercise 1***: Prove that $U_a$ is an open subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ in the box topology but that it is not an open subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ in the product topology.

***Exercise 2***: Prove that the collection of subsets of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ of the form $U_a$ where $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ is a sequence consisting of only $0$'s and $1$'s is an open cover of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ in the box topology.

***Exercise 3***: Does this open cover have a finite subcover?

The following problems should be of additional interest:

***Problem 1***: Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a collection of topological spaces. If the box topology on $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ is a compact topological space, what can you deduce about the $X_n$'s? In other words, how do the topologies on the individual $X_n$'s affect the compactness of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ in the box topology?

***Problem 2***: In the context of ***Problem 1***, if $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ is compact in the box topology, then prove that $X_n$ is compact for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

***Problem 3***: A topological space $X$ is said to be countably compact if every countable open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. Is $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ countably compact in the box topology?

I hope this helps!

Comment: Problem 1 is best set in the context of $T_1$-spaces; otherwise a complete answer gets a little messy. Assuming that one already has the Tikhonov theorem, Problem 2 has an easy solution that doesn’t require knowing the result of Problem 1. (Not a complaint, just an observation.)

Comment: @Brian Of course, you are right. I did not suggest that ***Problem 2*** requires ***Problem 1***; I only suggested that the notation of ***Problem 2*** is borrowed from ***Problem 1*** (thus, "In the context of ***Problem 1***"). Also, I do not think one needs Tikhonov's theorem to solve ***Problem 2***; one can note that the projection map $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n\to X_i$ is continuous for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. ***Problem 1*** is more of an open-ended problem; the OP is free to interpret the problem whichever way he/she chooses. If he/she chooses to assume the $T_1$-axiom, then this is fine.

Comment: Hi.  I took the liberty to fix the definition of countably compact in Problem 3.

Comment: Thank you so much @PatrickR !

Answer (score 4):

$$\left\{\displaystyle\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} I_n : I\in \left\{[0,\frac23),(\frac13,1]\right\}^\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

is an open cover of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the box topology that does not have a finite subcover.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\beta$ and $\pi$ be the box topology and the product topology on $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ respectively and consider the identity map$$\operatorname{id}\colon\left([0,1]^{\Bbb N},\beta\right)\longrightarrow\left([0,1]^{\Bbb N},\pi\right)\label{a}\tag1.$$Since $\beta$ is finer than $\pi$, it is continuous and clearly it is a bijection. So, since $\left([0,1]^{\Bbb N},\pi\right)$ is Hausdorff, if $\left([0,1]^{\Bbb N},\beta\right)$ was compact, then \eqref{a} would be a homeomorphism. But it isn't since, for instance, $(0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ is an open subset of $\left([0,1]^{\Bbb N},\beta\right)$ whose image is a non-open subset of $\left([0,1]^{\Bbb N},\pi\right)$.