# Let $[0, 1]^{\mathbb N}$ be equipped with the box topology.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, box-topology

Let $X = [0, 1]^{\mathbb N}$ be equipped with the box topology. Prove
or Disprove that

$[0, 1]^{\mathbb N}$ is connected.

From what I've known $[0, 1]^{\mathbb N}$ is not compact based on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60270/0-1-mathbbn-with-respect-to-the-box-topology-is-not-compact).
Now it bothers me if the latter is connected and how to show if it is or not.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1005021/447210) might help -- $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ is not a subset of any of the components, so it is not connected.

Comment: duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4205293